# Contenteditable div Remove <font>

Tags: javascript, html, contenteditable, font-size, nicedit

I have a contentEditable div with 14px as default font size. The default font size can be changed from a customization part (13-15px).

I added a button to change font size of selected text.

```
nicEditors.findEditor('myInstance1').nicCommand('fontSize', '5');
```

The button calls that function:

```
nicCommand : function(cmd,args) {
  document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
}
```

The result in the contentEditable div:

```
<font size="5">Such a</font>
```

It works but I can't find a way to remove `<font>` tag. So I tried to put null or 0 or -1 or 2 or 3 in the argument of `nicCommand` but the result size is not the same of the rest.

Is there anyway to remove or to move the `<font>` tag from a contentEditable div ?

To move in this case: You can have this `<font size="5">`Something is controlled by a cat.`</font>`. The user select "Something is" to remove "Something is" from `<font size="5">`. In this case `<font size="5">` must be placed after "is".

Comment: Apparently you're using NicEdit, so I've added that tag.

Comment: what do you want to get instead? `style="some px"`?

Comment: @vladkras: I want to be able to remove `<font size="5">`Such a `</font>` which has been added by a button.

Comment: Use a decent WYSIWYG editor. Such ones will have custom styles application support, bypassing the native implementations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an option of *document.execCommand* I had not seen and which works fine with  Firefox, Chrome and IE, *removeformat*:

```
nicEditors.findEditor('myInstance1').nicCommand('removeformat', null)
```

This calls that function:

```
nicCommand : function(cmd,args) {
  document.execCommand(cmd,false,args);
}
```

removeformat allows to remove all tags of the selected text. This remove as well as `<b>` as `<i>` as `<u>` as **`<font>`**. That's fine for me. :-)

Answer (score 0):

if you want just to delete it, use

```
var reg = /<font\ssize="\d+">(.*?)<\/font>/g;
str = str.replace(reg, "$1");
```

where `str` is a content of your editor

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vladkras/uFPD4/)

Comment: The problem is: You can have this `<font size="5">`Something is controlled by a cat.`</font>`. The user select "Something is" to remove "Something is" from `<font size="5">`. In this case `<font size="5">` must be placed after "is".

Comment: @defacto your question was "I can't find a way to remove <font> tag". Could you clarify what you really need to do?